# Fetch data from JSON server and automatically store in sqlite

Tags: iphone, json, sqlite

I want  to fetch data from JSON and store it automatically to sqlite whatever updated on server automatically updates to database whenever program runs. 
Can anyone help me out in it. And if my question is not sufficient to answer please ask anything required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) framework.  It takes care of the low-level API calls, object mapping, SQLite persistence, etc.  It's well documented and maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can start here http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

After reading this, you can user this Class, https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking. It's easy and usefull!

Answer (score 0):

Download JSON data with **[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)** and decode with **[JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)**, then you can save to SQLite with this wrapper **[FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)**.

Answer (score 0):

If your supporting iOS 5+ then JSON is added for you by default and can use it using the method given [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) and after getting the dictionary of objects , you can follow the normal procedure of adding them to sqlite or use core data as said by @Paras Joshi.